# Failing to load a module on udev event

Tags: linux, debian, usb, kernel-modules, udev

I have a pretty simple udev rule which is executed when a USB is plugged into my Debian machine:

```
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", KERNEL=="sd?", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/USB/t.sh \
%k"
```

My `t.sh` is also pretty simple and  it does two things:

- Prints helloworld in `udev.out` to Desktop
- Loads `foo.ko` module into kernel with simple `insmod foo.ko`

Or Concretely, `t.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'Hello World!' >>"/home/salman/Desktop/udev.out"

insmod helloworld.ko

exit
```

When I plug in my USB, `udev.out` is correctly printed on Desktop but the following line `insmod helloworld.ko` fails to load the module in the kernel.

I checked with `lsmod | grep helloworld` but it doesn't show `helloworld` loaded into kernel.

I am running a Debian machine inside Virtual Box.

Comment: It is generally not considered a good practise to cross-post the same question to several Stack Exchange sites. Maybe you could close the other one?

Comment: Have you verified that the `insmod` line actually succeeds when run interactively? Have you tried substituting `insmod helloworld.ko` with `modprobe helloworld` (without `.ko`)?

Comment: Try using absolute path for `helloworld.ko` with `insmod`